# AngularJS assign different params and functions

Tags: javascript, sql, angularjs

maybe this isn't a AngularJS problem but I guess I'm to new to this to understand what I'm doing wrong here. Can you please push me in the right direction? I tried this since more then 3 hours and getting depressive. :-(

I have a function in which I pass my SQL queries with other params. This function shall be flexible as much as it is possible.

```
prepareQuery('SELECT name FROM Lists WHERE id=(?)', [$scope.listId], listnameResultHandler(), defaultErrorHandler());
prepareQuery('SELECT * FROM Products', [], defaultResultHandler(), defaultErrorHandler());
```

To explain this:

1. param: SQL query
2. param: values bind to the query
3. param: the success-function, if the query is possible
4. param: the error-function, if there is a problem

Now here is the prepareQuery-function:

```
function prepareQuery(query, params, successHandler, errorHandler) {
    $scope.db.transaction(function(tx){
        tx.executeSql(query, params, successHandler, errorHandler);      
    }, errorCB); 
}
```

The problem is that I got always an answer from the defaultErrorHandler().

```
function defaultErrorHandler(err) {
  alert("Error processing SQL: " + err.code);
}
```

And the error always says: **undefined**.

Answer (score 2):

you need to pass function pointer, and not actually call them.
remove the brackets after function name `defaultResultHandler`

```
prepareQuery('SELECT name FROM Lists WHERE id=(?)', [$scope.listId], listnameResultHandler, defaultErrorHandler);
prepareQuery('SELECT * FROM Products', [], defaultResultHandler, defaultErrorHandler);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you are actually CALLING the error-handler instead of just passing it into the `prepareQuery`-function - and since you are calling it without parameters, the error itself is undefined. Try it like this:

```
prepareQuery('SELECT name FROM Lists WHERE id=(?)', [$scope.listId], listnameResultHandler, defaultErrorHandler);
prepareQuery('SELECT * FROM Products', [], defaultResultHandler, defaultErrorHandler);
```

Comment: Ok, that was the problem ... I guess. Now when I use console.log() in on of the successHandler I can see an answer. Great. 
BUT the errorHandler always showed up at the end. 
How can I debug this line:
`tx.executeSql(query, params, successHandler, errorHandler);`

Comment: You wanna debug the error handler? As long as there is no error, you dont need to. If there is one, it gonna show up through the implemented `alert` within the `defaultErrorHandler`-Func.